# Cordova geofence plugin issue iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, geofencing

I use Meteor in my project together with Angular. I'm trying to integrate the cordova geofence plugin (https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence) in iOS. When I install the plugin and execute the code below, the geofence will detect exiting a location only once. So when I enter the parameter again, it won't detect it. I've searched on the internet and found nothing concerning this particular issue.

Does anyone has a suggestion?

```
window.geofence.initialize().then(function () {
        console.log("Successful initialization");
        window.geofence.getWatched().then(function (geofencesJson) {
            var geofences = JSON.parse(geofencesJson);
            console.log(geofences);
        });
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error", error);
    });

    window.geofence.removeAll();
    window.geofence.addOrUpdate({
        id:             '10af5fab-39de-43df-b7a1-546cbbafc18c',
        latitude:       coord1, 
        longitude:      coord2, 
        radius:         10,
        transitionType: 3, 
        notification: {         
            id:             1, 
            title:          'HELLO', 
            text:           'Give test juice?', 
            openAppOnClick: true,
            data:           { _id:'sFkS9EJkHGJo9mYTP'}
        }
    }).then(function () {
        console.log('Geofence successfully added');
    }, function (reason) {
        console.log('Adding geofence failed', reason);
    });

    window.geofence.onTransitionReceived = function (geofences) {
        alert('go');
        geofences.forEach(function (geo) {
            alert('Geofence transition detected ' + geo);
        });
    };
```